# How to wrap child elements in a parent tag using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, insert, xmlstarlet

I want to wrap "table" elements with a new parent anywhere in the xml file. Am new using xmlstarlet.
Input:

```
<table>
</table>   
<oldTable>
    <table>
    </table>   
</oldTable>
    
Desired output:   
<newparent id="tab">
    <table>
    </table>    
</newparent>
     
<oldTable>
    <newparent id="tab">
        <table>
        </table>
    </newparent>    
<oldTable>
```

Comment: XSLT to the rescue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a POSIX shell:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  --var T '//table[not(parent::newparent)]' \
  -i '$T' -t 'elem' -n 'newparent' \
  -a '$prev' -t 'attr' -n 'typ' -v 'wtab' \
  -u '//newparent[following-sibling::*[1][self::table]]' \
  -x 'following-sibling::*[1]' \
  -d '$T' \
file.xml > newfile.xml
```

where:

- `--var T …` collect candidate `table` elements in variable `T`
- `-i` insert a `newparent` element before each `table`
- `-a` append a `typ` attribute to the element just created
- `-u` update all `newparent` elements having an immediately
  following `table` sibling element
  with (`-x` XPath expression) a deep copy of that sibling
- `-d` delete the copied siblings

`xmlstarlet edit` code can use the convenience `$prev` (aka
`$xstar:prev`) node to refer to the node created by the most recent
`-i (--insert)`, `-a (--append)`, or `-s (--subnode)` option.
Examples of `$prev` are given in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt).

Comment: It works on linux command-line. But I tried to put it inside a php code but it did not work:

    <?php
    exec("xmlstarlet edit \
      --var T \"//table[not(parent::newparent)]\" \
      -i \"$T\" -t \"elem\" -n \"newparent\" \
      -a \"$prev\" -t \"attr\" -n \"typ\" -v \"wtab\" \
      -u \"//newparent[following-sibling::*[1][self::table]]\" \
      -x \"following-sibling::*[1]\" \
      -d \"$T\" \
    file.xml > newfile.xml ");
    ?>

Comment: @Ofuuzo: Not familiar with PHP but I'd escape the `$` (dollar signs) inside double quotes, and delete the line continuation characters (backslash+newline) when the entire command goes in one line.